# Nginx and saleor configuration problems (Blocked by CORS policy)

Tags: nginx, cors, saleor

I am new to saleor.io which is an open source platform for e commerce apps and nginx. This saleor has three modules:

1. Saleor core (Django project, communicate with saleor store and saleor dashboard via graphql api's, connected to postgresql, Running on 192.168.0.102/grapghql/)
2. Saleor dashboard (Node project, containing javascript, type script files, Running on 192.168.0.102:70)
3. Saleor Store (Node project, containing javascript, type script files)

I am running these three modules on nginx and UI shows perfectly for each module.But when i try to login through dashboard i got this CORS error:

[image: CORS Error]

**This is my nginx configuration file for saleor core:**

```
upstream django {
     server unix:///home/umair/PythonDjangoProjects/GitSaleor/mysite.sock fail_timeout=9000; # for a file socket
   # server 192.168.0.102:80; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 192.168.0.102; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
         alias /home/umair/PythonDjangoProjects/GitSaleor/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/umair/PythonDjangoProjects/GitSaleor/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {

     uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/umair/PythonDjangoProjects/GitSaleor/uwsgi_params;  # the uwsgi_params file you installed
```

}
}

**This is my nginx configuration file for saleor dashboard:**

```
server {
    listen 70;
    listen [::]:70;
    root /var/www/html/dashboard;
    index index.html;
    server_name 192.168.0.102;
    location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }

}
```

How can i resolve this error?. Am i missing any thing in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try putting

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
}
if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
}
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
}
```

inside your saleor core location block.

More info here:
https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html